# Make a operation in a variable before prints the output

Tags: awk

I want to apply a condition to a variable inside of awk process.

How to add the below conditions in the code ot be able to do operations in the value variable (x1) and (x2) before to print the output file.

```
  #if{(x1>101) x1="AAA"}
  #if{(x2>104) x2="BBB"}
```

I would like to keep the code same as it is, for sure there a better way to do the same output, but in this case, I want to know how to do the operation in the variable.

**input file**

```
3141 37150 100 10100 1 4
3141 37201 100 12100 1 4
3144 37471 100 14100 2 5
3141 37471 100 14100 0 6
3141 37471 100 14100 5 6
3141 37471 100 14100 1 7
3142 37471 100 14100 3 8
3143 37471 100 14100 1 1
```

**The code I use**

```
awk '{
    tt1 = $1
    tt2 = $2
        tt3 = $3
    tt4 = $4
    tt5 = $5
    tt6 = $6
    x1 = tt3 + tt5
    x2 = tt3 + tt6 
    x3 = tt3 + tt2 

  #if{(x1>101) x1="AAA"}
  #if{(x2>104) x2="BBB"}

    x6 = x3 + 5000                       
    printf("%5d %5d %5d %5d %5d %5d %5d %5d %5d %5d\n", tt1,tt2,tt3,tt4,x1,x2,x3,tt5,tt6,x5)}' file1 | awk -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1}1'
```

**output file**

```
3141,37150,100,10100,101,104,37250,1,4,42250
3141,37201,100,12100,101,104,37301,1,4,42301
3144,37471,100,14100,102,105,37571,2,5,42571
3141,37471,100,14100,100,106,37571,0,6,42571
3141,37471,100,14100,105,106,37571,5,6,42571
3141,37471,100,14100,101,107,37571,1,7,42571
3142,37471,100,14100,103,108,37571,3,8,42571
3143,37471,100,14100,101,101,37571,1,1,42571
```

**desired output**

```
3141,37150,100,10100,101,104,37250,1,4,42250
3141,37201,100,12100,101,104,37301,1,4,42301
3144,37471,100,14100,AAA,BBB,37571,2,5,42571
3141,37471,100,14100,100,BBB,37571,0,6,42571
3141,37471,100,14100,AAA,BBB,37571,5,6,42571
3141,37471,100,14100,101,BBB,37571,1,7,42571
3142,37471,100,14100,AAA,BBB,37571,3,8,42571
3143,37471,100,14100,101,101,37571,1,1,42571
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do your first two lines of code contain only one closing curly bracket?  Where is the opening curly bracket?

Comment: Hi, Cyrus, sorry forgot the {

Comment: This is how it should work: `if(x1>101) {x1="AAA"}`

Comment: @OXXO, I have added mine version of answer as well as FIXED yours too, cheers(you could thank me later on this :) just kidding, cheers. Enjoy learning.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by `I would like to keep the code same as it is` (what is your desired outcome of this question if not different code?) and `I want to know how to do the operation in the variable.` (you're already performing operations on variables so what is it you want to do that you aren't doing?).

Comment: Hi Mr Ed, I was trying to add the option to subtract one variable if(x1>101) {x1="AAA"} with a condition the code works fine for me although is not good enough :(.. but the purpose was only to know how to do the mentioned request. Appreciate your help

Comment: Ravinder, many tks, actually the complete awk code i use is much bigger than the posted.. Many thanks your version..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I know you are asking to improve your code. IMHO best approach will be to use `printf` function and you could avoid using too many variables if any only if you DO NOT have any large program where we may need to use those variables(which we are getting from columns/fields values) later in program.

```
awk '{printf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%s,%s,%d,%d,%d,%d\n",\
      $1,$2,$3,$4,\
      $3+$(NF-1)>101?"AAA":$3+$(NF-1),\
      $3+$NF>104?"BBB":$3+$NF,\
      $2+100,$5,$6,$2+5000+$3)
}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
3141,37150,100,10100,101,104,37250,1,4,42250
3141,37201,100,12100,101,104,37301,1,4,42301
3144,37471,100,14100,AAA,BBB,37571,2,5,42571
3141,37471,100,14100,100,BBB,37571,0,6,42571
3141,37471,100,14100,AAA,BBB,37571,5,6,42571
3141,37471,100,14100,101,BBB,37571,1,7,42571
3142,37471,100,14100,AAA,BBB,37571,3,8,42571
3143,37471,100,14100,101,101,37571,1,1,42571
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Corrected OP's attempt here.

***OP's CORRECTED code solution as follows:***

```
awk '{
    tt1 = $1
    tt2 = $2
    tt3 = $3
    tt4 = $4
    tt5 = $5
    tt6 = $6
    x1 = tt3 + tt5
    x2 = tt3 + tt6 
    x3 = tt3 + tt2 
    x5=  x3 + 5000
  if(x1>101){x1="AAA"}
  if(x2>104){x2="BBB"}
    printf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%s,%s,%d,%d,%d,%d\n", tt1,tt2,tt3,tt4,x1,x2,x3,tt5,tt6,x5)}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
3141,37150,100,10100,101,104,37250,1,4,42250
3141,37201,100,12100,101,104,37301,1,4,42301
3144,37471,100,14100,AAA,BBB,37571,2,5,42571
3141,37471,100,14100,100,BBB,37571,0,6,42571
3141,37471,100,14100,AAA,BBB,37571,5,6,42571
3141,37471,100,14100,101,BBB,37571,1,7,42571
3142,37471,100,14100,AAA,BBB,37571,3,8,42571
3143,37471,100,14100,101,101,37571,1,1,42571
```

***Problems FIXED in OP's code:***

1- Removed `%5d` and changed it to `%d` to remove unnecessary spaces beteen digits printing.

2- Fixed delimiters in `printf` changed them to `,` in between.

3- Removed variable `x6` seems it was NEVER used and changed it to `x5`.

4- changed `if` condition's syntax. Seems Syntax was NOT right for it changed from `if{.....)` to `if(....)`.

5- Removed extra `awk` which was NOT being used after above changes in code.